# OpenSSL analogue for Java

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

Is there any way to do these OpenSSL operation using Java

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in private.pem -outform DER -out private.der -nocrypt
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform DER -out public.der
```

to generate private.der and public.der

Comment: You may get a  better response from Software Recommendations on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. In the meantime, you might check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-java/

Comment: @ErstwhileIII Sorry, but neither of those options are viable. That project is from 2005 and has no files. And this is a programming question, not a request for software.

Comment: @gagan1411, Are you asking how to execute the openssl commands from within a java program, or for how to do the equivalent work in Java?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII yes I was asking for the Java equivalent of this code. Anyway answer below works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
gen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair pair = gen.generateKeyPair();
try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("public.der"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
  os.write(pair.getPublic().getEncoded());
  os.flush();
}
try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("private.der"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
  os.write(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
  os.flush();
}
```

Comment: Should work, is the public key PKCS#1 encoded for both outputs? I'm pretty sure that the private key keeps to the (inner) ASN.1 definition of PKCS#8.